# Is there a "coroutine" feature in VB?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm programming a application and am wondering, is there a co-routine (or something similar) feature in VB?

In my application it pulls a picture from the internet and it takes quite a long time (30-45 seconds) and it stops all code from running while it does that. Here is the line of codes that pulls that picture:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/avimgs/" & Username.Text & ".gif").GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general-purpose method is to [create a background thread](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315577) yourself, as in other answers.

But many .NET components provide a built-in solution for performing their work asynchronously - always easier than manually creating threads. And the PictureBox [has support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awb8dkht.aspx) for asynchronous loading of images.

Here is the complete code from the MSDN sample, including error handling, cancelling the download and notification of completion. It couldn't be easier.

```
Private Sub loadButton_Click( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles loadButton.Click

    PictureBox1.LoadAsync("http://www.tailspintoys.com/image.jpg")

End Sub

Private Sub cancelLoadButton_Click( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles cancelLoadButton.Click

    PictureBox1.CancelAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_LoadCompleted( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles PictureBox1.LoadCompleted

    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Load Error")
    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
        MessageBox.Show("Load cancelled", "Canceled")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Load completed", "Completed")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the background worker process or create a seperate thread on your own.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem before creating a new thread on your own.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684640/advantage-of-using-thread-start-vs-queueuserworkitem

Comment: Creating threads is fun, but why not just use the built-in support for asynchronous loading in the PictureBox. `PictureBox1.LoadAsync("http://www.tailspintoys.com/image.jpg") `

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the image in a *background thread*. See the following document for details on threads:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315577

Comment: Thanks! What I did is have a load thread to see if a Boolean is true, and if it is to load the image.

Answer (score 1):

[Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) per se are not implemented in .NET. You will have to use a thread for this. I have played around a bit with fibers and .NET but there are some significant technical issues to making that work  in a managed environment. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949051/is-there-a-fiber-api-in-net) has some good discussion and links.